# Why doesn't my script work while it always worked fine?

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I try to insert a $_POST and a $_SESSION and another value i gathered.
It did always work, till now.
Could someone help me out? Its PHP and MySQLi.

CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../inc/db/config.php');
$s_user = $_SESSION['user_name'];

$server_ip = $_POST['isamp_server'];
$server = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/json/samp/?address=' . $server_ip)), true);
$s_name = $server['hostname'];

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    trigger_error('Fout bij verbinding: '.$mysqli->error);
}

$s_ip = $mysqli->real_escape_string($server_ip);

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO servers ( 
        serverip, 
        servername,
        username,
        createtime) 
    VALUES ( 
        '".$s_ip."', 
        '".$s_name."', 
        '".$s_user."', 
        NOW())"; 

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
    trigger_error('Fout in query: '.$mysqli->error); 
}
else
{
    header('Location: ../index.php'); 
}
?>
```

I've tried everything i can, it just doesn't work, keep getting a white screen like something is wrong. There is no error message that looks like a mistake in the query.
Someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: ^^ -- _Always_ do this when developing code. A white screen in PHP when output is expected usually means a fatal error. (syntax error, missing extension, faulty `require`, etc)

Comment: Also check your HTTP error log. You may find something useful there.

Comment: You can use try catch block to see exception errors..

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the tip, i've added it and out of nowhere instead of that it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome, so problem solved I take it?